# Why does this range object contain the correct address in the worksheet, but is located in a different worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

The workbook is structured in such a way (the list being the worksheets): Overview, May 2021, June 2021, July 2021 etc etc

I'm writing a subroutine which goes into each sheet after the overview sheet, finds the column with the names and then adds each name into the names column in the Overview sheet if the name is not already there. This is the code:

```
Sub GetNames()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer, WS As Integer ' declare variables for loop below
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count ' variable for loop, used to loop through all worksheets nic Overview
        
    For WS = 2 To WS_Count ' loop through all worksheets nic Overview
    
        Dim NamesList As Range, Name As Range, NameChecker As Range ' declare variables for loop below
        Set NamesList = Range(Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range("B3").Row, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range("B3").Column), Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range("B3").Column))
        MsgBox NamesList.Address
        MsgBox NamesList.Worksheet.Name
        For Each Name In NamesList
            MsgBox Name.Worksheet.Name
            MsgBox Name
            NameChecker = Sheets("Overview").Range("B:B").Find(What:=Name.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If NameChecker Is Nothing Then
                Sheets("Overview").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Text = Name.Text
            End If
        Next Name
            
    Next WS

End Sub
```

I get an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error for the 3rd line after the inner most for loop.

I tried using MsgBoxes to see what was going wrong (if there is an easier way to quickly check variable values then please let me know I'm very new to vba), and for the NamesList variable, while it is returning the correct range where the names are, which would only work if it was looking in the correct worksheet, when I go to check which worksheet the range is referencing from it comes back as being the overview sheet which does not make sense to me as it should be starting from the second worksheet in the workbook.

Could anyone explain why this is, and any general suggestions for the code would be great as well.

Thanks so much

Comment: You need to use `Set` in VBA to assign objects. `Set NameChecker = Sheets("Overview").Range("B:B").Find...`

Comment: Btw: Is this related to Mac-OS?

Comment: @FunThomas oh yeah, thanks for that, but it doesn't make the code work as the nameslist range is still in the wrong worksheet, I also put macos as thats what I'm working on

Comment: Using _range_ and _cells_ without defining a worksheet the active worksheet is used.

Comment: @Shrotter So, I tried defining the worksheet when using Range and setting the NamesList variable by making the line

```Set NamesList = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range(Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range("B3").Row, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range("B3").Column), Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Range("B3").Column))```
However, that also returns an error, and I'm not quite sure why

Comment: _if there is an easier way to quickly check variable values then please let me know I'm very new to vba_ You could use `F8` to step through the code row by row, hover over a variable and it will give a pop-up showing the value.  You could also add variables to the `Watch` window, view them in the `Locals` window or use `Debug.Print <variablename>` to show them in the Immediate window.

Comment: @Shrotter I included the line ```ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WS).Activate``` before setting the NamesList variable rather than the other change I suggested and its returning the right worksheet, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`NameList` will always look at the currently active sheet as you haven't qualified the range.

This version may work better - it doesn't matter if you move the `OverView` sheet to another position.

```
Public Sub GetNames1()
    
    'Look at each sheet in the workbook, ignoring "Overview".
    Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
    For Each WrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'ThisWorkbook = the book containing this code.
        Select Case WrkSht.Name
            Case Is <> "Overview"
                With WrkSht
                    'Get the NameList range and copy it to the bottom of the "Overview" list.
                    Dim NameList As Range
                    Set NameList = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
                    'Haven't qualified Rows.Count here - it only really matters if you're using a mix of XL2003 and later.
                    NameList.Copy Destination:= _
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                End With
        End Select
    Next WrkSht
    
    'Remove duplicates from the "Overview" list.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much, I do think that would work better, only thing is, does the removeduplicates function prioritise the duplicates after the first one it finds?

Comment: I _think_ `RemoveDuplicates` keeps the first occurrence of a value it finds.